# Oracle database ALTER SESSION

Tags: oracle

I have logged in as system user. 
So I have two plugable databases 
1) PDB$SEED
2) PDBORCL

Now I want to alter session and need to set the container to pdborcl . But it is giving me error like below.

```
SQL> ALTER  SESSION  SET  CONTAINER  =  pdborcl;
ERROR:
ORA-65024: Pluggable database PDBORCL is not open.
```

Note: I also changed my tsnames.ora file like below

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\SgMadankar\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL = 
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL = 
  (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE = DEDICATED)
       (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE PDBORCL open;` or `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL open;`

Comment: I am getting below error:    SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL open;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: Are you connected to root container as a sysdba?

Comment: I think yes.  I am using "sqlplus /  as  sysdba " this command and entering username as system and my password. Then it is showing that i am connected.   Am i right here?

Comment: You could use `sys as sysdba` when it prompts for the username.

Comment: It works. Thnks @JSapkota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You need to connect with a user with SYSDBA privilege, SYS would be good.

2- You need to open your pluggable database.

```
SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN;
```